# Error while migrating TFS 2018 update to Azure DevOps 2020.0.1

Tags: tfs

I am working to migrate TFS 2018 update to Azure DevOps 2020.0.1 and I am getting the below error on the server configuration wizard. I have installed the Search on TFS 2018 update and Elastic search service is up and running.

[Info   @11:27:45.482] +-+-+-+-+-| Running General: Verifying that all the inputs are valid and there are no violations |+-+-+-+-+-
[Info   @11:27:45.972]
[Info   @11:27:45.972] +-+-+-+-+-| Verifying that all the inputs are valid and there are no violations |+-+-+-+-+-
[Info   @11:27:45.972] Starting Node: VINPUTS
[Info   @11:27:45.974] NodePath : VINPUTS
[Error  @11:27:45.978] The following input is not in a valid form: ElasticsearchPassword.  Reason:
[Info   @11:27:45.982] Node returned: Error
[Error  @11:27:45.984] The following input is not in a valid form: ElasticsearchUser.  Reason:
[Info   @11:27:45.984] Completed General: Error

[image]

Comment: Don't post images of error messages. Post the text.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: There is no code, It's an azure DevOps server configuration wizard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My issue was resolved after updating the Windows with the latest updates.